# Why was my question closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

My question [How to use Superpowered Audio SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60030622/how-to-use-superpowered-audio-sdk) was closed for being "Off topic".

The description for off-topic is: 
"We don’t allow questions seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more. Edit the question so it can be answered with facts and citations."

Great, I can see why a question that met those criteria might be closed, however, I don't see my question meeting any of them.

As for seeking recommendations, I can see two plausible ways for that to be interpreted; Asking which SDK/etc I should use, or asking (In the case of an SDK) which solution for a given problem is best.

I'm clearly not asking which SDK I should be using, as specified in the title and tags. And I'm not asking for an opinion on multiple solutions, just for *a* solution which, unless I've massively misunderstood the point of this site, very much so *is* the point of SO.

In addition, there is quite literally a tag for the specific SDK, which I used, filled with questions of a similar format to mine

As for whether or not it can answered with facts or not, I think it pretty obviously can; a simple example of how to solve my question would be pretty hard to make non factual.

So why was my question closed? If for a valid reason, how can I improve it? If not, can it be reopened?

Comment: Because you seem to be asking for instruction on how to use the software. That's not a programming question it's a request for tutorials and that isn't what we do.

Comment: @Paulie_D It's an SDK, not software, so I feel like it is a programming question. Here's some examples of open questions on the SDK of a similar structure: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58867083/is-there-a-way-to-detect-the-amplitude-of-a-sample-in-real-time-processing, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56889226/tomcat-kind-of-implementation-with-superpowered-with-voice-modulation, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51273517/in-superpowered-is-it-possible-for-the-equalizer-filters-to-go-below-20hz.

Comment: @Paulie_D I don't feel I'm asking for a general tutorial either, I asked how to write audio samples to the audio buffer, while being able to specify some variables such as sample rate.

Comment: If you are asking for basic instructions then that's essentially asking for tutorials. You have to look elsewhere for that level of basic help.

Comment: Use of the “off site resource” close reason for questions that are actually too broad has never made sense to me. It seems intentionally confusing to accuse askers of wanting off site tutorials when they’re actually asking for answers that would be too long.

Answer (score 19):

Your question title is *"**How to use** Superpowered Audio SDK"*, and the first sentence says *"Title pretty much says it all, **how do you use** the damn thing?"* (emphasis mine). So this is not a specific enough question for Stack Overflow.

That question could only be satisfactorily answered by providing complete, working code for a (simple) programming project. Assuming you don't expect a Stack Overflow user to write a complete sample project for you (and you shouldn't expect this), the only way your question could be properly answered is by a link to an existing sample project, i.e. an off-site resource. Therefore your question is either "too broad", or a "request for off-site resource recommendations". Both are reasons a question can be closed.

In the comments here you wrote, *"I asked how to write audio samples to the audio buffer, while being able to specify some variables such as sample rate."* That may be what you intended to ask, but what you actually asked was *"how to use [the SDK]?"* which clearly doesn't get the more specific point across.

Regarding tips for improving your question, I suggest comparing your question with **upvoted** questions that have the same tag; the first one I found was [Latency/clicking sound when looping a player with Superpowered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56945088/latency-clicking-sound-when-looping-a-player-with-superpowered). This one describes a specific narrow problem, has a specific title, and contains code so that someone answering the question can work out what particular thing is missing or wrong in that code.